# .NET find .xls or.xlsx file with GetFiles using wildcard? example: .xls*

Tags: vb.net, xls, xlsx, getfiles

I need to find an Excel file. However, the extension  of the file I"m looking for could be .xls or .xlsx. I was considering using FileExists but I can't use a wildcard with that. Here's my attempt at using GetFiles, however, the .xls* part of my code does not work. I've never used GetFiles before, can anyone give me some guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim InputFormPath As String = "W:\TOM\ERIC\NET Dev\"
Dim wbNameXLSInputForm As String = StatVar.xlApp.Sheets("New Calculator Input").Range("D15").Text & ".xls*"
Dim XLSInputForm As String = wbNameXLSInputForm
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles(InputFormPath, wbNameXLSInputForm)

If dirs.Length <> 0 Then
'do something
End If
```

Comment: Apparently, you are doing everything fine. Both options should work in your situation: InputFormPath & StatVar.xlApp.Sheets("New Calculator Input").Range("D15").Text & ".xls*" and "*" & InputFormPath & StatVar.xlApp.Sheets("New Calculator Input").Range("D15").Text & ".xls" With these two filters you should get both the xls and xlsx versions (and any other one like xlsm).

Comment: Where is DimXLSInputForm being used and where is wbNameXLSInputForm defined?

Comment: @ SeanCarroll...switched my variables around when posting, just edited my post and added

Comment: Take a look at this documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx. Specifically it says The following list shows the behavior of different lengths for the searchPattern parameter: "*.abc" returns files having an extension of.abc,.abcd,.abcde,.abcdef, and so on.

Comment: @SeanCarroll you are right. As said, his code should work without any problem. What is not right is your actual answer, please delete it or just update it with the comment you have written right now.

Comment: @varocarvas, he has ".xls*" which is not the same as "*.xls". these two are different hence why i provided the link and text.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx). It says: The following list shows the behavior of different lengths for the searchPattern parameter: "*.abc" returns files having an extension of.abc,.abcd,.abcde,.abcdef, and so on.

Comment: I've done that, thanks, but it still doesn't seem to be finding the file. I'm going to to keep tinkering, but do you think it could it be my "If dir.Length" line? The syntax for the GetFiles line seems correct

Comment: If I hard-code ".xlsx" it finds and opens the file. However, using the wildcard as suggested does not find the file. The documentation says it should work, but I'm not having any luck here